# What is the value of $ \frac{AH}{AD}+\frac{BH}{BE}+\frac{CH}{CF}$ where H is orthocentre of an acute angled $\triangle ABC$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, plane-geometry

**SOURCE**: ***SAMPLE QUESTION OF BD MATH OLYMPIAD***.

> In an acute-angled triangle ABC, AD, BE and CF are respectively perpendicular to the opposite side of the three climax point included A, B and C. H is the orthocentre of the orthogonals. What is the value of $ \frac{AH}{AD}+\frac{BH}{BE}+\frac{CH}{CF}$?

***Liklier figure of the problem:***

[image]

*Thanks in advance for your respective effort*.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is not a question of being a professional mathematician :) Most of us are learners. However , the community better appreciates questions , which the OP has clearly spent time on , and is truly interested in . It makes it worthwhile to answer such questions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[PQR]$ denote the area of $\triangle PQR$
[image]
Consider the figure . We have :- $$ \frac{AH}{AD}+\frac{BH}{BE}+\frac{CH}{CF}=\frac{AD-DH}{AD}+\frac{BE-HE}{BH}+\frac{CF-HF}{CF}$$ $$=3-(\frac{DH}{AD}+\frac{HE}{BH}+\frac{HF}{CF}) $$
Now , $$\frac{DH}{AD}+\frac{HE}{BH}+\frac{HF}{CF} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}BC\cdot DH}{\frac{1}{2}BC \cdot AD}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot HE}{\frac{1}{2}AC \cdot BH}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}AB \cdot HF}{\frac{1}{2}AB \cdot CF} $$ $$= \frac{[BHC]+[CHA]+[HAB]}{[ABC]}=1$$
Therefore , the answer to your question equals $3-1=\boxed2$

Comment: This was really helpful. But is there any theorem or postulate about this or similar problem?

Comment: Not that I know of . But a tip would be to keep areas in mind , when considering the orthocentre and perpendiculars.